# Problems with Zonal Statistic in graphical modeler QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I want to make an average of two rasters previously generated in a model but it always gives error. I have used both SAGA and GDAL to calculate the raster out of graphical modeler without problems, but using the algorithm in the model gives the following error:

```
File "C: /PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis /./ python / plugins \ processing \ algs \ saga \ SagaAlgorithm.py", line 187, in processAlgorithm
if parameters [param.name ()]. source (). lower (). endswith ('sdat'):
AttributeError: 'QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition' object has no attribute 'source'
```

[image: Model]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how you set up your model and the parameters of the statistics tool?

Comment: Of course. Thanks in advance